# Adding elements to front and back of char array of unknown size?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I find it puzzling that you can't know how long an array is if you didn't initialise it (in current scope) i.e. only having a pointer to the array, but functions like `printf` can utilise the `char` array's null terminator to work out when to stop printing.

Is there a library function or simple algorithm that allows me to find out the length of an array only given it's pointer?

My problem is that I am passing a char array to a function to add quotation marks `"` around it to indicate it being a string to be passed to a python script to handle properly. Since the incoming string can be variable length, I can't just initialise a char array of given length and manipulate it there which is why I'm trying to find the length of the incoming char array.

How would I add elements to the front and back of a char array with unknown size?

Code:

```
    void format_ip(char *ip, char *ptr_to_new_ip){

        //sizeof(ip) here obviously returns the size of a pointer in memory
        //Instead, I need to find the actual length of the array

        char array[sizeof(ip) + 2];
        memcpy(array + 1, ip, sizeof(ip));

        array[0] = '\"';
        array[sizeof(ip) + 1] = '\"';

        memcpy(ptr_to_new_ip, array, sizeof(ip)+2);
    }
```

EDIT: Due to a lack of a formal posted answer, this was solved by using `strlen` which returns the length of a null terminated char array given the pointer to it. Thanks to [Tio Pepe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855378/tio-pepe) for the answer.

Comment: if your `ip` array is null ending, you can use `strlen`

Comment: I _knew_ it had to be this easy. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, what you call a "pointer to an array" is no such thing. It is just a pointer.

Comment: Also I'd probably agree to the dupe marker if the question linked even had as good an answer as the one above. I'd suggest removing the dupe marker so you don't accidentally drive away visitors that think that post has an answer that solves it as concisely as this one.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm not saying that the pointer has any type. I'm clarifying that the pointer indeed points to a char variable and that being the first element in an array that is of topic.